# If $y>0$ show that $\exists n \in N$ such that $1/2^n < y$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

If $y>0$ show that $\exists n \in N$ such that $1/2^n < y$.

I tried this way

$S:=[1/m:m \in N]$

we know $inf(S) = 0$

for $y > 0$

y is not a lower bound of S, therefore,

$\exists n \in N$ such that $1/n \in S$ and

-> $1/n<y $------eq1

also $2^m > m$ ---- $\forall m \in N$

putting m=n we have,

$2^n > n$

-> $1/2^n < 1/n$--------eq2

from eq 1 and 2

$1/2^n < y$

Can someone confirm if this argument in correct ?

Comment: It's kinda correct, but the claim that $\inf(S) = 0$ is pretty similar to what you're trying to prove.

Comment: As a more general remark: if you write a proof, try to use full sentences. This requires perhaps some more work, but it makes it easier for readers to follow your proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have proven the [Archimedean Principle](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle),
\begin{align*}
y > 0 &\implies 1/y > 0 \\
&\implies \exists n\in\mathbb{N} : 0 < 1/y < n <  2^n \\
&\implies 1/2^n < y.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

by contradiction we have that $\displaystyle\exists y >0: \forall n \in \Bbb{N}: \frac{1}{2^n}\geq y$. Because $y>0$ and $\displaystyle \forall n\in \Bbb{N}:2^n >0$ we have $\displaystyle\frac{1}{y}\geq 2^n$, but $\forall n\in \Bbb{N} :2^n\geq n$ therefore $\displaystyle\frac{1}{y}\geq n $, it means $\displaystyle\exists y >0: \forall n \in \Bbb{N}: \frac{1}{y}\geq n$ therefore $\displaystyle \frac{1}{y}$ is upper bound of $\Bbb{N}$ (Absurd!)